# Setting up QT creator for ROS

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to ask whether there are any tutorials on how to setup the QT creator so that I can include ROS code into it. i am interested in using the QT creator to create a GUI that can publish msgs to control other parts of my ROS program. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11661/setting-up-qt-creator-for-ros/) by [MoggyQuek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1276/moggyquek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-10-24

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no need to set it up. Just [create a package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage), open its CMakeLists.txt with QtCreator and you are done.

If you are not accustomed to using CMake with Qt you can have a look at [this page](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects). Getting to know CMake might require some reading, but I do not regret ditching qmake for CMake.

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MoggyQuek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1276/moggyquek/) on 2011-10-27**:
I had tried creating a package and use QTCreator to open the CMakeLists.txt. However, it seesm that CMake is unable to detect the rosbuild cmake file due to the environment variable $ENV(ROS_ROOT). Is there any way to correct this problem?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-06-14**:
@MoggyQuek can you provide the error message that you got when `Qt Creator` was "unable to detect `rosbuild` cmake file" as you described? I'm just curious and I haven't seen that error

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey MoggyQuek regarding your problem about the undetected environment variables -
if you have already exported the variables as described in [Required_ROS_Environment_Variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#Required_ROS_Environment_Variables), then try starting QtCreator directly in a terminal like this:

/.qtcreator

now the variables will be available.

---

Originally posted by [grim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1357/grim/) with karma: 101 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9